# Writing to a sensor register using i2c bitbanging library not working - PiGPIO library on Raspberry Pi

Tags: i2c, pigpio, bit-bang

I am trying to configure a sensor connected to Rpi over an i2c bus. I am using PiGPIO library with Python to do this. To configure the sensor, I need to write a certain value to some registers and that doesn't seem to be working.

I am doing the following to write value to a register.

```
pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, i2c_address, 2, 7, 1, register_address, 2, 7, 1, value, 3)
```

Register address could be 0x0A, and value being 0x04.

When I read the register back, it reads the default value that the sensor came with. So I know the writing doesn't work but reading does. For reading, I do the following and it works

```
pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, i2c_address, 2, 7, 1, register_address, 2, 6, 1, 3)
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to write to registers using PIGPIO library. Does anyone have had any success in doing something like this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your sensor work when you connect it to dedicated I2C pins?

Comment: Why aren't you using standard I2C?  Please edit the question and include the full test code.

Comment: The Raspberri Pi model 3 has a hardware bug that doesn't allow for clock stretching. The bitbang library is a workaround to do that on a Pi. The sensor works when I connect it to dedicated pins.